# JQuery: Code snippets Conflicting on 'Hover'

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table as shown below,

```
<table class="table" style="border:2px solid black; width:100%">
<tr>
    <th><h4>New Request</h4></th>
    <th><h4>Existing Request</h4></th>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="colorhover" style="border-right:2px solid lightgrey; width:1%;">
            @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_NewRequest.cshtml", Model);}
        </td>
        <td class="colorhover" style="width:1%;">
            @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_ExistingRequest.cshtml", Model);}
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Which when the table body is hovered over colors the background a shade of green. using :

```
$(".colorhover").hover(
//hover
function () {
    $(this).css("background", "#CEF6CE");
},
//dehover
function () {
    $(this).css("background", "");
})
```

Also when either column is hovered over, the cursor is placed in the top text input of either column.
using:

```
$("#newrequesthover").hover(function () {
    $("#imei").focus();
    $("#filtername").blur();
});

$("#existingrequesthover").hover(function () {
    $("#imei").blur();
    $("#filtername").focus();
});
```

This works fine, my problem is when I click on one of the selects drop-down in the new request partial view. My cursor is taken to the top text input and the select drop-down immediately closes,

so how can I prevent this when hovering over the selects?

Comment: have a look into [e.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).  As an aside, why are your `tds` 1% width? why not 50%?

Comment: setting a smaller than needed size for the columns (e.g. width="1%"), is so that the column would auto-adjust to the minimum size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to stop event propagation. Just add

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

to the select event. You also need to make sure the select event is fired first, i.e. define that event first in your script.

Comment: Thanks, heres the code snippet i used:

    $("#DD1").hover(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    })